# valueChanged(const Qstring &) not fired in qspinbox when empty

Tags: c++, qt, qspinbox, qt5.12

I'm having a QSpinbox inside a QTreeWidget following an approach similar to the approach for a combobox described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/4849010/10220019.

I've read here https://forum.qt.io/topic/103667/qdoublespinbox-why-isn-t-valuechanged-signal-fired-when-content-is-empty/5 that if you use the `valueChanged(const QString&)`signal this should fire when you backspace from a number to empty. However this is not the case for me. The only difference I can see between that post and my code is that I use a QSpinBox and not a QDoubleSpinBox but that shouldn't be the problem I guess.

I think I might be connecting the signal wrongly because the behavior I get completely matches the behavior I would expect from valueChanged(int). But I wouldn't know how to write the connect then. Does somebody see the error?

My code is:
QTreeWidgetItemSpinBox.h

```cpp
#pragma once

#pragma warning (push)
#pragma warning (disable: 26451 26495 26498 26439)
#include <QtWidgets/QSpinbox>
#include <QtWidgets/QTreeWidget>
#include <QtWidgets/QToolTip>
#pragma warning (pop)

class QTreeWidgetItemSpinBox :
    public QSpinBox
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    QTreeWidgetItemSpinBox(QTreeWidgetItem* treeItem, int column);

public slots:
    void validateValue(const QString& input);

private:
    QTreeWidgetItem* treeItem;
    int column;
};
```

QTreeWidgetItemSpinBox.cpp

```cpp
#include "QTreeWidgetItemSpinBox.h"
#include <QtCore/QDebug>

QTreeWidgetItemSpinBox::QTreeWidgetItemSpinBox(QTreeWidgetItem* treeItem, int column)
    : treeItem(treeItem), column(column)
{
    connect(this, SIGNAL(valueChanged(const QString&)), SLOT(validateValue(const QString&)));
}

void QTreeWidgetItemSpinBox::validateValue(const QString& input)
{
    qDebug() << "Called"; //Is called when changed to another number but not if the change is to empty or if I add zeros before a number
}
```

Comment: Try Qt 5 Connection syntax with right signals `connect(this , &QSpinBox::valueChanged , &QTreeWidgetItemSpinBox::validateValue);`

Comment: Actually it would be `connect(this , QOverload<const QString &>::of(&QSpinBox::valueChanged), &QTreeWidgetItemSpinBox::validateValue);`  But it won't make any difference how the connection is made.

Comment: @MaximPaperno "It won't make any difference how the connection is made" so why is there a difference in syntax then? Why would one be preferred over the other?

Comment: https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why that Qt forums post says `QDoubleSpinBox::valueChanged(const QString &)` is emitted when the value is blank because it is not (as of Qt 5.12 anyway). Both versions of the signal are emitted consecutively from the same place in [the code](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/widgets/qspinbox.cpp.html#_ZN21QDoubleSpinBoxPrivate11emitSignalsE10EmitPolicyRK8QVariant).  Maybe it was different in a previous version.  Same for `QSpinBox`.  I guess the reasoning is that since the value is invalid, it hasn't actually changed (because eg. if you lose focus/finish editing right then, it will auto-revert to the last known good value... so the value hasn't actually changed).

You could instead connect to the `QLineEdit` (obtained with `QAbstractSpinBox::lineEdit()`) `textChanged()` (or `textEdited()`) signal to get the actual value of the editor.

Comment: Could you give me the code for the connect since how I do it I get the error "no such signal"

Comment: Okay the connect was not difficult, but I just didn't say it for some time. For others with the same problem, the connect would look like this: ````QLineEdit* lineEdit = QAbstractSpinBox::lineEdit();
 connect(lineEdit, &QLineEdit::textChanged,this, &QTreeWidgetItemSpinBox::validateValue);````